# List Comprehension error in Python

Tags: python, input, list-comprehension

I'm working on a code in which in need to use a comprehensive list to calculate the y-axis values, using the input of x-axis values. I have two questions. First, I need to figure out how to use the values in my input list xx:

```
 print("How many x-axis values do you have?")
 xv = input("-->")
 print("What are your x-axis values? Put in each value and press enter.")
 xx = []
 while len(xx) < int(xv):
  item = float(input("-->"))
  xx.append(item)
```

and use those values inside the list comprehension:

```
y = [(a(x**2))+ bx + c) for x in xx]
```

When I run this, it says: Type error: 'str' object is not callable

My second question is that a,b, and c are also input, and i need to be able to put them in there too, but can't figure out how.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: `bx` isn't the product of `b`and `x`; `b*x` is. And `a(something)` isn't `a` times `something`, but an attempt to *call* the value of `a` as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("How many x-axis values do you have?")
xv = input("-->")
print("What are your x-axis values? Put in each value and press enter.")
xx = []
while len(xx) < int(xv):
    item = float(input("-->"))
    xx.append(item)
a=float(input("a?:"))
b=float(input("b?:"))
c=float(input("c?:"))
y = [(a*(x**2)+ b*x + c) for x in xx]
```

Like this?

Comment: I already have that in there, i need to know how t specify that that input is to be used it the comprehensive list.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand you, what's the issue with my code? (note that I slightly changed your list comprehension)

Comment: I already have the a = input. i need to know how to say in the y =, that the a,b, and c, are the ones i just input

Comment: My code does that? Have you even ran it? It will use the last a/b/c that is defined in the current scope.

Comment: sorry, I'm still a bit new to coding and i didn't realize. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't understand mathematical syntax in the same way you and I do. You need to explicitly specify all mathematical operations you perform.

```
a(x**2)
```

Doesn't mean "a times (x to the power of 2)", but rather "invoke the method 'a' with 'x to the power of 2' as the argument). You want to do this instead:

```
a * x**2
```

Note that the exponential operator has precedence over multiplication so there is no need for the parenthesis.

Similarily, you can't write 'bx' but you need to write b * x.

It also seems that 'a' is a string so you need to convert it to an int or a float before using it in mathematical expressions.

```
print("How many x-axis values do you have?")
xv = input("-->")
print("What are your x-axis values? Put in each value and press enter.")
xx = []
while len(xx) < int(xv):
 item = float(input("-->"))
 xx.append(item)
a, b, c = map(float, (a, b, c))
y = [(a * x**2 + b * x + c) for x in xx]
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Joshua you need to have a*x**2 + b*x + c for the second part of your question I am not sure what you are asking but I think what you want is:

```
    a,b,c = eval(input("Please input a,b and c separated by a comma: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y = [(a(x**2)+ bx + c) for x in xx]
```

var a is a string type; you can not multiple like this "a(x**2)", it is a calling function in python;
change to :

```
y = [(a*(x**2)+ b*x + c) for x in xx]
```